# Filtering a JTable in a Java program

Tags: java, swing, search, filter, jtable

I have a little problem about filtering a JTable.

Updating, Adding and Filtering stocks are working fine. When I add stocks, of course it will display on the table. Same with filtering, when I search any letter or word it will display or not depending if the searched product is available.

The problem is like this, when I tried to delete a specific product, it won't delete and an error will be shown as stated below. The error is about the changing of cell colors.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 >= 0
at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:474)
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.getValueAt(DefaultTableModel.java:648)
at javax.swing.JTable.getValueAt(JTable.java:2719)
at javax.swing.JTable.prepareRenderer(JTable.java:5720)
at VapeShop.Inventory$1.prepareRenderer(Inventory.java:55)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintCell(BasicTableUI.java:2114)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintCells(BasicTableUI.java:2016)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paint(BasicTableUI.java:1812)
at javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(ComponentUI.java:161)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:777)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1053)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5217)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1532)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1455)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1252)
at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5165)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4976)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:811)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:794)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:794)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:769)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:718)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1100(RepaintManager.java:62)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1680)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:744)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:714)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

I tried removing the code about changing the cell colors but there still an error without stating what line it was. So I don't know what to do about it.

The error code is shown below:

Inventory.java:55 is the "Component c = super.prepareRenderer(r, data, columns);"

```
itemTable = new JTable(model){
        public boolean isCellEditable(int data, int columns){
            return false;                                       //Cell Uneditable
        }  
        public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer r, int data, int columns){   //Changing of Cell Colors
            Component c = super.prepareRenderer(r, data, columns);
            if(data % 2 == 0)
                c.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            else
                c.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

            if(isCellSelected(data, columns))
                c.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

            return c;
        }

    };
```

This is the code of filtering my table:

```
else if(btnSource==btnSearch){
            String getSearch = txtSearch.getText();
            if(rowCount==0){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Inventory is Empty.","Note!",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
            else{
                sorter.setRowFilter (RowFilter.regexFilter (getSearch));
                sorter.setSortKeys (null);
            }
        }
```

That's just my problem. I'm not sure if the problem is about filtering or deleting my table because if I remove the code about filtering, the program works fine but when I put it back again, error will be prompted.

Here is the full code:

```
package VapeShop;

import static VapeShop.Style.*;

import java.awt.*;

import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import javax.swing.table.*;

public class Inventory extends JFrame{

    static JPanel inventoryview;
    JLabel bg, lblInventory;
    JTextField txtInventory, txtSearch;
    static JTable itemTable;
    JButton btnSearch, btnAdd, btnBuy, btnDelete, 
            btnUpdate, btnLogout;
    JScrollPane scrollPane;
    final TableRowSorter sorter;
    static Object[][] data = new Object[0][6];
    static String[] columns = new String[6];

    public Inventory(){
        bg = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\DPdieciocho\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Database 2\\src\\Images\\bg.png"));
        add(bg);

        inventoryview = new JPanel();
        inventoryview.setLayout(null);
        inventoryview.setOpaque(true);
        inventoryview.setBorder(border);
        inventoryview.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        inventoryview.setBounds(128, 85, 750, 400);
        bg.add(inventoryview);

        lblInventory = new JLabel("Inventory");
        lblInventory.setFont(font5);
        lblInventory.setForeground(Color.white);
        lblInventory.setBounds(270, -2, 250, 45);
        inventoryview.add(lblInventory);

        txtInventory = new JTextField();
        txtInventory.setBounds(-1, -1, 750, 50);
        txtInventory.setEditable(false);
        txtInventory.setOpaque(false);
        txtInventory.setBorder(border);
        inventoryview.add(txtInventory);

        columns = new String[] {"No. of Stock", "Product Code", "Item", "Category", "Type", "Class", "Price (PHP)"};
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel (data, columns);

        itemTable = new JTable(model){
            public boolean isCellEditable(int data, int columns){
                return false;                                       //Cell Uneditable
            }  
            public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer r, int data, int columns){   //Changing of Cell Colors
                Component c = super.prepareRenderer(r, data, columns);
                if(data % 2 == 0)
                    c.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                else
                    c.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

                if(isCellSelected(data, columns))
                    c.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

                return c;
            }

        };


      sorter = new TableRowSorter (model);
      itemTable.setRowSorter (sorter);


        itemTable.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);             //Undraggable Columns
        itemTable.setSelectionMode (ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);   //Selecting a Single Row Only
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(itemTable);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrollPane.setBounds(2, 80, 747, 320);
        inventoryview.add(scrollPane);

        buttons();

        String e_smoke = "Images/smoke.png";
        java.net.URL imgURL = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(e_smoke);
        ImageIcon smoke = new ImageIcon(imgURL);

        JLabel lblImage = new JLabel(smoke);
        lblImage.setBounds(0, 0, 1280, 500);
        bg.add(lblImage);

        ActionListener listener = new ButtonListener();
        btnBuy.addActionListener(listener);
        btnUpdate.addActionListener(listener);
        btnSearch.addActionListener(listener);
        btnAdd.addActionListener(listener);
        btnDelete.addActionListener(listener);
        btnLogout.addActionListener(listener);

    }

    public void buttons(){
        String search = "Images/search.png";
        java.net.URL imgURL = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(search);
        ImageIcon searchthis = new ImageIcon(imgURL);

        txtSearch = new JTextField();
        txtSearch.setFont(font6);
        txtSearch.setBorder(border1);
        txtSearch.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
        txtSearch.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        txtSearch.setBounds(485, 55, 175, 20);
        inventoryview.add(txtSearch);

        btnSearch = new JButton(searchthis){
          public JToolTip createToolTip() {
            JToolTip tip = super.createToolTip();
            tip.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            tip.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            tip.setFont(font4);
            return tip;
          }
        };
        btnSearch.setBounds(665, 53, 22, 22);
        btnSearch.setFocusable(false);
        btnSearch.setBackground(Color.gray);
        btnSearch.setBorderPainted(false);
        btnSearch.setToolTipText("Search Item");
        btnSearch.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        btnSearch.setOpaque(false);
        inventoryview.add(btnSearch);

        String add = "Images/add.png";
        java.net.URL imgURL1 = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(add);
        ImageIcon addthis = new ImageIcon(imgURL1);

        btnAdd = new JButton(addthis){
          public JToolTip createToolTip() {
            JToolTip tip = super.createToolTip();
            tip.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            tip.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            tip.setFont(font4);
            return tip;
          }
        };
        btnAdd.setBounds(693, 53, 22, 22);
        btnAdd.setFocusable(false);
        btnAdd.setBackground(Color.gray);
        btnAdd.setBorderPainted(false);
        btnAdd.setToolTipText("Add new Item");
        btnAdd.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        btnAdd.setOpaque(false);
        inventoryview.add(btnAdd);

        String delete = "Images/delete.png";
        java.net.URL imgURL3 = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(delete);
        ImageIcon deletethis = new ImageIcon(imgURL3);

        btnDelete = new JButton(deletethis){
          public JToolTip createToolTip() {
            JToolTip tip = super.createToolTip();
            tip.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            tip.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            tip.setFont(font4);
            return tip;
          }
        };
        btnDelete.setBounds(720, 53, 22, 22);
        btnDelete.setFocusable(false);
        btnDelete.setBackground(Color.gray);
        btnDelete.setBorderPainted(false);
        btnDelete.setToolTipText("Delete Item");
        btnDelete.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        btnDelete.setOpaque(false);
        inventoryview.add(btnDelete);

        String buy = "Images/buy.png";
        java.net.URL imgURL2 = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(buy);
        ImageIcon buythis = new ImageIcon(imgURL2);

        btnBuy = new JButton(buythis){
          public JToolTip createToolTip() {
            JToolTip tip = super.createToolTip();
            tip.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            tip.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            tip.setFont(font4);
            return tip;
          }
        };
        btnBuy.setBounds(10, 53, 22, 22);
        btnBuy.setFocusable(false);
        btnBuy.setBackground(Color.gray);
        btnBuy.setBorderPainted(false);
        btnBuy.setToolTipText("Buy new Item");
        btnBuy.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        btnBuy.setOpaque(false);
        inventoryview.add(btnBuy);

        String update = "Images/update.png";
        java.net.URL imgURL4 = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(update);
        ImageIcon updatethis = new ImageIcon(imgURL4);

        btnUpdate = new JButton(updatethis){
          public JToolTip createToolTip() {
            JToolTip tip = super.createToolTip();
            tip.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            tip.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            tip.setFont(font4);
            return tip;
          }
        };
        btnUpdate.setBounds(38, 53, 22, 22);
        btnUpdate.setFocusable(false);
        btnUpdate.setBackground(Color.gray);
        btnUpdate.setBorderPainted(false);
        btnUpdate.setToolTipText("Update Quantity");
        btnUpdate.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        btnUpdate.setOpaque(false);
        inventoryview.add(btnUpdate);

        String out = "Images/logout.png";
        java.net.URL imgURL5 = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(out);
        ImageIcon logout = new ImageIcon(imgURL5);

        btnLogout = new JButton(logout){
          public JToolTip createToolTip() {
            JToolTip tip = super.createToolTip();
            tip.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            tip.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            tip.setFont(font4);
            return tip;
          }
        };
        btnLogout.setBounds(965, 500, 18, 22);
        btnLogout.setBackground(Color.gray);
        btnLogout.setBorderPainted(false);
        btnLogout.setToolTipText("Log out");
        btnLogout.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        btnLogout.setOpaque(false);
        bg.add(btnLogout);
    }

    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            Object btnSource = e.getSource();     
            int rowCount = itemTable.getRowCount();
            int rowCheck = itemTable.getSelectedRow();   

            if(btnSource==btnBuy){
                dispose();
                new BuyItem().run();
            }

            else if(btnSource==btnUpdate){
                if(rowCount==0){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Inventory is Empty.","Note!",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
                else if(rowCheck<0){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Select the item to be updated.","Note!",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
                else{
                    new UpdateItem().run();
                }
            }

            else if(btnSource==btnSearch){
                String getSearch = txtSearch.getText();
                if(rowCount==0){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Inventory is Empty.","Note!",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
                else{
                    sorter.setRowFilter (RowFilter.regexFilter (getSearch));
                    sorter.setSortKeys (null);
                }
            }


            else if(btnSource==btnAdd){            
                dispose();
                new AddItem().run();
            }

            else if(btnSource==btnDelete){

                if(rowCount==0){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Inventory is Empty.","Note!",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
                else if(rowCheck<0){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Select the item to be deleted.","Note!",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
                else{
                    Object[][] temp = new Object[data.length-1][7];
                    for(int i=0; i<rowCheck; i++){
                        temp[i][0] = data[i][0];
                        temp[i][1] = data[i][1];
                        temp[i][2] = data[i][2];
                        temp[i][3] = data[i][3];
                        temp[i][4] = data[i][4];
                        temp[i][5] = data[i][5];
                        temp[i][6] = data[i][6];
                    }
                    for(int i=rowCheck+1; i<data.length; i++){
                        temp[i-1][0] = data[i][0];
                        temp[i-1][1] = data[i][1];
                        temp[i-1][2] = data[i][2];
                        temp[i-1][3] = data[i][3];
                        temp[i-1][4] = data[i][4];
                        temp[i-1][5] = data[i][5];
                        temp[i-1][6] = data[i][6];
                    }
                    data=temp;
                    itemTable.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(data, columns));
                }
            }

            else if(btnSource==btnLogout){
                int selected = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Are you sure you want to Sign out?","Confirm Sign Out",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                if(selected == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
                    dispose();
                    new Admin().run();
                }
                else if(selected ==JOptionPane.NO_OPTION){
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void run(){
        setSize(1000, 562);
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation (EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Inventory().run();
    }
}
```

I don't know how to fix this because this is my first time in using JTable.

Comment: Too much code to look at. Start with the example from the Swing tutorial on [Sorting and Filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting). Add you "Delete" button to that code and get it working. Then compare that working code with your code to see what the difference is.

Comment: @camickr I tried the filtering process stated at [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) but same error was prompted. It's about the changing of cell colors. About the delete button, actually there is a delete button in my code which deletes a specific row clicked by the user but error prompts in if the code about filtering is concluded.

Answer (score 1):

Your delete method seems way too complicated. All you need to do use is use the `removeRow(..)` method of the `DefaultTableModel`.

The code would be something like:

```
//int index = table.getSelectedIndex(); 
int index = table.getSelectedRow(); 
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();
model.removeRow( table.convertRowIndexToModel( index );
```

If this doesn't help than post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) based on the tutorial example, not your current code.

Comment: @iamprogrammer: `"isn't working"` doesn't tell us much.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I mean. the word getSelectedIndex(); has a color red underline which means that syntax may be wrong.

Comment: @iamprogrammer then it will also have an error message. Read what it says critically.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels 
"Cannot find symbol.
Symbol: method getSelectedIndex()
Location: variable itemTable of type JTable"

Comment: @iamprogrammer: that should probably be `table.getSelectedRow()`

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, `that should probably be table.getSelectedRow()` - indeed it should.

Comment: @iamprogrammer, just wondering if you checked the API for a method that might make sense (since sometimes my fingers don't type what the brain is thinking). By reading the API you do learn about more methods to help you solve problems.